# How to show the progressbar when upload the video file using multipartentity

Tags: java, android

i am upload video file and data using multipartentity .How to show the progressbar and upload the Array values in one key value?

I am using the following code:

```
                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Call_Server.REPLAY_VIDEO);
                MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                        HttpMultipartMode.STRICT);
                mpEntity.addPart("FILE_UPLOAD", new FileBody(videofile));
                mpEntity.addPart("message_id", new StringBody(recipient_id));
                mpEntity.addPart("recipient_email", new StringBody(recipient_email2));
                totalSize = (int) mpEntity.getContentLength();
                System.out.println(totalSize + ":::::totalSize");
                httppost.setEntity(mpEntity);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Thread to upload data, and use runOnUiThread to show progress bar.  Also you can use asyn task.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use [Async Task](http://toolongdidntread.com/android/android-multipart-post-with-progress-bar/) threading function.